# Why am I getting a MemoryError?

Tags: python, list

Why am I getting a MemoryError when my code is only 13 lines long? Could it be because I could potentially be getting a very long list?

I am trying to return a list of a sequence of numbers here (the list will be x and then the numbers obtained until 1). The sequence will be complete when the variable val reaches 1.

```
def sequence(x):
    my_list = [x]
    val = 0
    while (val!= 1) and (x != 1):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            val = x / 2
            my_list.append(val)
        else:
            val = 3 * x + 1
            my_list.append(val)
    return my_list
print(sequence(6))
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File ******, line 12, in <module>
    print(sequence(6))
  File ******, line 7, in sequence
    my_list.append(val)
MemoryError
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: The value of x never changes so the loop either never starts or never ends.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are not manipulating x. So, x will always be 6.
And as x will always 6, your val will never be equal to 1 in both cases

```
val=x/2      #will result in val=3
```

And also

```
val=3*x+1    #will result in val=19
```

So, both conditions ( val != 1 ) and ( x != 1 ) will always True and your loop will not terminate at all.
This infinite loop goes on filling your list and eventually you will get memory error.

Hope you got it.